# Nibiru hypothesis

Tags: xenobiology, civilization, rocky-planets

Starting from the infamous "Nibiru hypothesis", I'd like to craft a world identical or at least similar to the one described within the works (more SF than Hard Science if you ask me) of Sitchin. It is a planet with very precise features, and I would like to receive help about its feasibility.

I have a long set of doubts but since they are connected, I will go down the list gradually.

First and most important question:

Is it possible, for a planet which is so far from the Sun it receives nothing of its heat, to still harbour an Earth-like temperature, relying only on internal heat, 4.5 billions years after its formation?

The planet I have in mind has a thick atmosphere and a superficial gravity 2 to 3 times the one of Earth.

In case the answer is favorable, how should I proceed with further inquires within this website?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140962/discussion-on-question-by-fringesexplorer-nibiru-hypothesis).

Comment: "I would like help about its feasibility." We are asked "Is X feasible?" all the time. It's irritating. The [help/on-topic] clearly states we're here to help you design an imaginary world. Yes, there are people who want to design as closely as possible to known physics (we're not gods, we don't know what's "feasible"), and we can help with that, but asking us to judge if a 3rd party/comasiblemercial world is "feasible" is off-topic. We don't answer questions about other people's worlds. Finally, there are a lot of questions on this Stack about rogue worlds. What has searching taught you?

Comment: BTW, Worldbuilding doesn't care about the Nibiru hypothesis. If your imaginary universe wants a big, unknown planet outside the Sol system, let's build it. If you want a rogue wanderer, let's build it. If you want to discuss, debate, examine, or do anything else with the Nibiru hypothesis, you're on the wrong Stack.